# Inconsistent handling of HTTP Header in recv() function

Tags: c, apache, http

I want to get the HTTP receive header from a message using the code below, but sometime it works well and sometimes it doesn't.

Here is my code to send:

```
send(s, message, strlen(message), 0)
```

And this is how I receive data:

```
int memory = 1;
int d = 0;
header = malloc(memory * sizeof(char));
if (header == NULL) {
    printf("Error, memory\n");
    return 1;
}
while (recv(s, header + d, 1,0)>0) {
    if(strstr(header, "\r\n\r\n") != NULL)
        break;

    d++;
    if (d >= memory) {
        memory *= 2;
        header = realloc(header, memory);
        if (header == NULL) {
            printf("Error, memory\n");
            return 1;
        }
    }
}
```

I think it some problem with `malloc`, but I can't find where.

This is a successful receive header, according to [w3.org](https://www.w3.org/TR/ldp/images/ldpc-hierarchy.png):

```
Header:
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Sat, 02 Apr 2016 02:35:07 GMT
Last-Modified: Tue, 24 Feb 2015 20:49:22 GMT
ETag: "7ab4-50fdba7431880;50c0cc9312bdc"
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Content-Length: 31412
Cache-Control: max-age=2592000
Expires: Mon, 02 May 2016 02:35:07 GMT
P3P: policyref="http://www.w3.org/2014/08/p3p.xml"
Vary: upgrade-insecure-requests
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Connection: close
Content-Type: image/png; qs=0.7
```

And this is one from a failed message, according to [apk-dl](http://apk-dl.com/detail/screenshot/DueSGNGTIpribKe93O72-pJU6zgEp7qN_agFirScA9OVXmWLV8ofyAZngl0Q_Sc-K50=h500.png):

```
Header:
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
gEp7qN_agFirScA9OVXmWLV8ofyAZngl0Q_Sc-K50=h500.png HTTP/1.1
Host: apk-dl.com
Connection: close
```

How can I get my function to decode the header correctly and consistently?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cannot work because of failure to correctly and completely handle the result returned by recv(), misuse of strxxx() calls on character arrays that are not guaranteed null-terminated, failure to comprehend the octet-stream nature of the underlying TCP protocol that can only transfer messages of one byte or less and misuse of malloc - only allocates one byte for the header buffer.

Answer (score 0):

The `strstr` function is only for C-style strings. You can't use it for arbitrary data. One possibility is to use a `memmem` type function like [this](http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/Libc/Libc-825.40.1/string/FreeBSD/memmem.c).

I would strongly urge you to stop sending HTTP 1.1 requests and send HTTP 1.0 requests instead. There are a lot of things you have to get right to make an HTTP 1.1 client (such as handling chunked encoding) that you'd probably rather not deal with.

Comment: Still not working, i changed it to memmen and also changed HTTP request to 1.0. Bu still i get just part of header.
`Header:
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Sat, 02 Apr 2016 03:00:33 GMT
Content-Type: image/png
Connection: close
Set-Cookie: __cfduid=d88ceea80daa7c7da249e58e3e 
`